# data is entering multiple time in db when using ajax and jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am sort of new in PHP, so i am not really good in debugging. i am trying this for a while now and after not getting anywhere, i decided to put it here and hope if i can get solution.
i have information on page with edit and add buttons on screen. when i am adding any entry, it is getting there (on main page as well as DB (mySQL)for multiple times. there is a pattern that I observed in my case. when i am using  add button for first time there is no repetition. when i do it for 2nd time i got 2 repetitions,3rd time i get 4 repetition, 4th time 8 ,5th time 16 and 6th time 32 time. So it is making a series like 1, 2,4,8,16,32.

***What I am trying to do …***

On add button I am opening a form on model and collecting info from there. On save of that model form, I am calling a jquery function and with the help of AJAX. I am using a third page to perform DB operations. after the insertion info is getting prepended on same section. I am sharing a piece of code of AJAX part and hope it is helpful for debugging .
thanks for everyone who put some effort even if I don’t get a solution.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#saved-education").click(function () {
            //         alert("insside save-edu");
            var msg1 = $("#education-course").val();
            var msg2 = $("#education-board").val();
            var msg3 = $("#education-school").val();
            var msg4 = $("#education-start-year").val();
            var msg5 = $("#education-end-year").val();
            var msg6 = $("#education-grade").val();
            //       alert(msg1 + msg2 + msg3 + msg4 + msg5 + msg6);
            var content = '&em1=' + msg1 + '&em2=' + msg2 + '&em3=' + msg3 +
                    '&em4=' + msg4 + '&em5=' + msg5 + '&em6=' + msg6;
            $.ajax({
              url: "ajexupdate.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: content,
              dataType: 'text',
              cache: false,
              success: function (e) {
                //      alert(e);
                $("#dislay_education_1").html(e);
                $("#modal-edu").modal('hide');
              }
            });
            return false;
          });
```

**PHP UPDATE CODE**

```
if (isset($_POST['em1'])) {
  $edu_id = generate_random_edu_id();
  $course = $_POST['em1'];
  $board = $_POST['em2'];
  $school = $_POST['em3'];
  $start_year = $_POST['em4'];
  $end_year = $_POST['em5'];
  $grade = $_POST['em6'];
  $eduation_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user_education`(`edu_id`, `course`, `board`, `school`, `start_year`, `end_year`, `grade`, `uid_fk`,`colg_id`) VALUES ('$edu_id','$course','$board','$school','$start_year','$end_year','$grade','$user_id','$colg_id')", $db1);
  $education_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `user_education` WHERE  `uid_fk` ='$user_id' AND `edu_id`='$edu_id' ORDER BY edu_created DESC LIMIT 1", $db1);
  $education_result = mysql_fetch_object($education_query);
  }
```

**HTML FORM**

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Duration</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <select id="education-start-year" name="start_year" >
                    <option disabled="disabled">From</option>
                    <?php
                    $year = range(2017, 1900);
                    foreach ($year as $d) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $d; ?>" <?php   if ($row_edit_exp->start_year == $d){ echo selected; } ?> > <?php echo $d; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            <label class="control-label" for="textinput"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <select  id="education-end-year" >
                    <option disabled="disabled">From</option>
                    <?php
                    $year = range(2017, 1900);
                    foreach ($year as $d) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $d; ?>" <?php   if ($row_edit_exp->end_year == $d){ echo selected; } ?> > <?php echo $d; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div> <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button type="button" id="saved-education" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly add your code so we can figure out what you've tried yet.

Comment: sorry for delay just added it.

Comment: Can you post ajexupdate.php too ?

Comment: sure plz wait a min

Comment: It looks fine maybe you're calling ajax twice please post html code from where you're calling

Comment: sure plz wait..

Comment: I think, problem is with this line ( $("#dislay_education_1").html(e); ). This line is inserting 'educations' and 'id=saved-education' button multiple times in 'id=display_education_1' div. so $("#saved-education").click event is getting fired multiple times.

Comment: when i am am opening the alert in AJAX section i am getting the whole AJAX part written inside alert.

Comment: @Muhammad Inaam Munir  $("#dislay_education_1").html(e); this part is for only binding updated view to main HTML part on main page.why do u think it is calling the function multiple times..?

Comment: can you show what is being returned in 'e',  ( success: function (e) {  ). I think 'e' is having multiple buttons 'id=saved-education'

Comment: https://unsee.cc/dotupeba/

Comment: kindly visit the link. when i just un-comment the alert in success:function(e) i start getting this , on alert as a message.

Comment: posted the html form at the end of my code

Comment: @Muhammad Inaam Munir... thanks  Munir for helping with the idea. i resolved it myself, but the idea u suggested played a key role in this. thank a lot again and i would make it answer if it was not a comment.

Comment: @AkhileshChandel, You are welcome. You can upvote my comment which helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the answer , was not found by entering something new piece of code.it was found through a debugging suggestion made by Saad suri. i cant rate him up as i dont have enough repo.
actually i was including the JS function in my AJAX file too, to make sure the edit and delete in HTML view that was displayed on front end was still working. so i included the JS in AJAX page just to make sure the buttons were still working in the updated view. this was causing the multiple entering in Db.
thanks saad for your suggestion and sorry i cant rate your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.....

```
$("#saved-education").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

....
....


})
```

Comment: e.preventDefault(); this is even stopping the jquery execution. when i press the save button it is not going inside query

Comment: @AkhileshChandel To disable a submit button, you just need to add a disabled attribute to the submit button. $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);